# How to add data to SQL Azure through GSM Modem?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, gsm

I recently worked with Hyper Terminal on windows 7 in which i access SMS received through a GSM SIM card on my laptop port and using GSM Modem Device connected to my PC.
Demo Application here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38705/Send-and-Read-SMS-through-a-GSM-Modem-using-AT-Com

Now i have an account on windows azure and i do have a sql azure database named `PersonInfo` in which i want to add some data from my SIM sms. The data is like '253 Mobulite NetTimeet'
and i want to send this SMS using my SIM and want it to store at Azure Databse table.

Please suggest what options do i have ? How can i achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why all the down votes but lets go through this.

You have an application that needs to store data, from data it receives or sends via SMS.

**GSM Model communication**

From your tags I can see you want to develop and app in c#. You will need to communicate to the GSM modem most likely via COM/Serial ports. Just looking at the link you provided, I assume that is how you are doing things. The hyperterminal comment threw me, I'm not sure why you mentioned it.

**Data Storage Options**

1. Local SQL
   If it is just 1 computer I would suggest, installed a DB on your local machine and using that.
2. SQL Azure
   I would only recommend this if you had multiple locations that all needed to read off the same database. Otherwise if it is all on just 1 pc and the data doesn't need to be available online then use a local DB.

**C# To Database**

1. Use Entity Framework. Quick walkthrough here: http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/a-quick-guide-to-using-entity-framework

Comment: When you see the follow up questions, you'll understand the down votes and votes to close.

Comment: I don't mind a few follow up questions. People come to stack overflow for help. As they spend more time on the site, they learn to ask clearer, more concise questions. Occasionally they go too far and keep asking away, in which case I just say here's a link, read it and learn it.

Comment: A good question doesn't generally need follow ups. But this question could have multiple books written about it. I'm not here to do people's basic research for them. Hover over the down vote arrow and you'll see this question is a perfect example. And this ian't a brand new user; he's been asking open-ended questions since day 1, and some have even been up voted onxe or twice. He'll never learn with that sort of thing happening, imo.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - ok you were right, he ended up creating another account and asking the same types of questions, not even returning to this one to upvote or accept. He needs to learn.